# Exit android webview if authentication failed

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, android-webview

My android application has a custom login page. Once a user submit the username and password with my custom login page, the program will redirect user using WebView and insert those information into the login form and submit the form with the following JavaScript code

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {" + 
        ... // insert the data into the form
        ... // submit the form
    );
}
```

However, If a user input a wrong password, let say I know the url contains "signin" means the authentication failed, how do I use this condition to redirect user back to MainActivity page(which is my custom login)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess You could use a simple if/else and an **Intent** (in case of failure) with an alert or something to redirect your user back to your login page.